# Правильно отключить tinymce

Tags: jquery, tinymce, javascript

При клике по элементу к textarea добавляется редактор tinymce. При клике по другому элементу, хочу чтобы tinymce убивался и его следов не оставалось на странице, но не могу разобраться как.

```
tinyMCE.get('content').remove();
```

Вот такая конструкция (выше) примерно убивает редактор, однако посмотрев в консоль ошибок, замечаю, что срабатывает автосохранение, которое не находит нужных элементов на странице и вызывает ошибку. Так же, при повторном "применении" редактора к textarea (id = content) редактор появляется, но в поле с текстом пусто, при этом при нажатии на кнопочку HTML открывается модальное окно, в котором есть нужный html код, находящийся в <textarea id="content"></textarea>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тоже задавался этим вопросом. Ответ нашел на их сайте. Вообщем если кратко, то для правильного удаления:

```
if(tinyMCE.get('content')) {
             tinyMCE.execCommand('mceFocus', false, 'content');
             tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, 'content');

         }
```

А для создания:

```
tinyMCE.execCommand("mceAddControl", true, "content");
```

Фишка с фокусом при удалении, если я не ошибаюсь нужна только для эксплореров 6 версии. Хотя я для эксплорера 6 вообще отключить хочу свой сайт в будущем (т.е. не весь сайт, а только отдельную его js-часть), но на всякий случай оставил)

Comment: Спасибо!
Как оказалось, эта штука: tinyMCE.get('content').remove(); - тоже работает как надо, просто я не правильно вызывал init (http://hashcode.ru/questions/97315/jqgrid-tinymce - вот тут ответ как правильно вызывать (jqgrid и tinymce))

Comment: А вы там вызываете функцию init при каждом клике (т.е. редактировании строки)? Если да, то можно же этого не делать. Можно просто один раз ее вызывать и все. А при клике на строку таблицы (если я правильно понял, никогда не работал с jqgrid и поэтому не знаю что это такое) просто делать следующее:

     tinyMCE.execCommand('mceSetContent', tinyMCE.get('content'), 'текст который нужно показать');

Это намного меньше будет грузить компьютер клиента. Это просто совет. Конечно, можно и без этого обойтись.